# Integral Differential equation

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a set of differential equations of the form:

```
x1dot = x3;
x2dot = x2;
x3dot = x1;
x4dot = x2 + integral(x1,t,tend)
```

I have the boundary condition for `x1`, `x2` at `tstart` and `x3`, `x4` at `tend`. Without the integral term it's a straight forward implementation using `BVP4C`.

I am wondering if it is possible to have the previous solution for the states from the BVP solver which can be used for the integral.

One possibility is using `ode45` and `fsolve` in combination for the boundary value problem, where I can have the previous solution, but this approach is not as fast as the BVP setup.

I also feel that there may be some difficulty in convergence when I use the previous solution, `x1`, for the integral.

Is there a better/quicker or easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO (the asking side, anyway), and kudos for the well-formed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
x5 = integral(x1,t,tend)
```

then

```
x5dot = -x1  with  x5(tend) = 0
```

Since `x5dot + x3dot = 0`, it follows that `x5 + x3 = C = const`. Therefore you can use the substitution `x5 → C - x3`.

The constant `C` is simply `C = x3(tend) + x5(tend) = x3(tend)` (because `x5(tend) = 0`).

Comment: +1: Most fools are easily blinded by false complexity; it often takes a genius to see the inherent simplicity.

Comment: ...I'm a fool apparently, because I'm struggling to see why there is a minus sign (`x5dot = -x1`), and why `x5(tend) = 0`...can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Using the fundamental theorem and `X1` as one of the anti-derivatives of `x1`, one has that `x5(t)=X1(tend)-X1(t)`. Differentiating that and applying `X1'(t)=x1(t)` gives the differential equation `dotx5 = -x1`. Trivially for `t=tend` the integration domain is one point and thus the integral zero, `x5(tend)=0`

Comment: ...OK, I guess I need more coffee :)